# The method setPosition(CGPoint) in the type CCSprite is not applicable for the arguments (float, int)

Tags: android

I am developing a basic game.And when i was developing a scence, i  got this error message(The method setPosition(CGPoint) in the type CCSprite is not applicable for the arguments (float, int)).how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 4):

it is from the cocos2d, isn't it? then you should modify this:

```
target.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(winSize.width + (target.getContentSize().width / 2.0f) , actualY/ 1.0f));
```

Answer (score 1):

i am using the setPosition(CGPoint) like this way you should try it..

```
deleteMenu.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp((hintSprite.getContentSize().width - 10), hintSprite.getContentSize().height + 10));
```